# bug will converting 3-hourly data into daily data in python using resample

Tags: python, resampling

Blockquote

I got 3-hourly data and i would like to convert them into daily data in a new matrix in Python. I tried something like that but it seems to be wrong, I'm a beginner...

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('temp_2019.csv')

p_num=df1.values[:,1].astype(np.float)
time_vec=df1.values[:,0].astype(str)
time_vec=pd.to_datetime(time_vec)
df2=[time_vec,p_num]

daily_values = df2.resample('D').mean()
```

But it told me that 'list' object has no attribute 'resample', i don't know what's wrong...

Thanks a lot for your help

[here is a view of my matrix df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IeH9.png)
[here is a view of my matrix df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bo8V.png)

Comment: Share the database pls

Comment: `df2` is a list containing two elements, `time_vec` and `p_num`. Did you mean to `merge` or `join` those things into a dataframe?

Comment: For more specific help, please provide sample input and output so that we can better understand your problem, to make a [mcve]

Comment: okey i dont really understand how to share the database but here is a view of my matrix df2 and df1, do you want the complete excel?

Comment: yes it's a good idea but the function resample in not working with dataframe, it says it's only valid with DatetimeIndex